# angular: binding to scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bind

I am trying to follow this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

Now I have this in my script file:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [
       'scroll',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ngRoute']);

var scrollService = angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        console.log("binding");

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
          console.log("scrolling");
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The HTML file (in `jade` notation) has:
EDIT: I added an id and the CSS

```
div#lista_iniciativas.row(when-scrolled="loadMore()")
```

Then the

```
#lista_iniciativas {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`

Thing is I can see the "binding" log in the console, but never the "scrolling", even debugging I never get to enter the bind function...In other words the binding function never fires. Any idea what's wrong here? Am I binding somewhat the wrong way?

Comment: 'binding' would fire where ever you put the directive, can you show more about your html or duplicate the issue in jsfiddle or some? if 'scroll' event is not fired.. are you using the directive over a valid div? or the right element, is important to overflow attr be: 'auto' or 'scroll'..

Comment: @rahpuser Thanks for chiming in. I am using a valid `div` as `elm`, indeed I can see it's the right one in the debugger. And it has `overflow 'auto'` (tried with `scroll` as well). So far I got a step further by injecting `$document` into the function and binding on that - that works...I would not know what else you'd like in a fiddle?

Comment: ok, so you already fix it ?.. I was asking for a jsfiddle that reproduce the issue you got.. also, I suggest to throttle or debounce the scroll function..

Comment: well yes, it's somehow fixed, although I don't understand why the code in the post didn't work...

Comment: how did you fix it ? actually the code in the post works.. I already try that code

Comment: interesting....I'll post my own solution...it's probably not the best but it works for me now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found worked for me.

It's probably not the best solution, and @rahpuser reported that the code in the original post actually DOES work...so....

```
var scrollService = app.directive('whenScrolled', function($document, $window) {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        $document.bind( 'scroll', function() {
          if( ($window.innerHeight + $window.scrollY) > getDocHeight() - 100) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
          } 
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Interesting.. so you are injecting $document and doing the bind to $document.. can you show your HTML too? for me seems like you were using the wrong DOM element because, if I'm not wrong, $document is a wrapper to window.document, and a bind over that is like a bind over body right ?

Comment: maybe the container of the element is scrolling too, so you could see the scroll but the scroll doesn't belongs to the div you want. Can you check this out? my guess is that your container (maybe body ) starts to overflow and put a scroll, then your div is inheriting the height of the container, so that when you use $document is working.. does your div have a fixed height ?